# Flexbox | Get the effect of “space-between” with dynamically sized flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to get the effect of justify-content and align-items with value "space-between" on my flex box, but I can not use them as there is no static width/height for the flexbox. I can not use margins because its adding space to all sides. I only want space on sides where flex items would meet.

Ultimately, my goal is to have the very left and very right sides of the flex box's content to be aligned with division above it, but with some amount of space between the items. How can I get this done?

There will be several more flex items added/removed, so I can not have it hacked to limit support on the 3 boxes used as a demonstration for my issue below.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container div {
  flex: 1 1 300px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>Flex item sides should align with this division's sides</div>
<br>
<div id="container">
  <div>Box 1</div>
  <div>Box 2</div>
  <div>Box 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable that there is there is more or less only 2 ways, where one use either a margin or the border, and an extra wrapper that compensate for the gap

Stack snippet

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: none;
  margin: -5px 0 0 -5px;      /*  compensate for the gap  */
}

#container .wrapper div {
  flex: 1 1 300px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;        /*  5px between  */
}

#container2 .wrapper div {
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;        /*  5px between  */
}
```

```html
<div>Flex item sides should align with this division's sides</div>
<br>
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>Box 1</div>
    <div>Box 2</div>
    <div>Box 3</div>
    <div>Box 4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<div id="container2">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>Box 1</div>
    <div>Box 2</div>
    <div>Box 3</div>
    <div>Box 4</div>
    <div>Box 5</div>
    <div>Box 6</div>
    <div>Box 7</div>
    <div>Box 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the padding from the `#container` div. Apply padding to the inner div using `#container div`...

set `margin-bottom` to the inner elements...and also remember to remove the `margin-bottom` from the last inner element using `:last-child`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container div {
  flex: 1 1 300px;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container div:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Box 1</div>
  <div>Box 2</div>
  <div>Box 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#container div {
  flex: 1 1 300px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

#container div:first-of-type{
  margin-top:0;
}

#container div:last-of-type{
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    Box 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Box 2
  </div>
  <div>
    Box 3
  </div>
</div>
```

If so, just got to "delete" the margin-top from the first flex item (which you can target with first-of-type) and the margin-bottom from the last (which you can target with last-of-type)

Comment: This assumes that the box is small enough to force all items into a single column. I want space on all sides where flex items would meet; such as when there are several rows and collumns. My web-app limits the row count to be two. I have rephrased the post

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
}

#container div {
  flex: 1 1 300px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    Box 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Box 2
  </div>
  <div>
    Box 3
  </div>
</div>
```

If this does not resolve your query, please re-phrase it for us.

Comment: I have rephrased the post.

Comment: in this case, remove all the margins and use "width:300px;" instead of "flex: 1 1 300px;" in your #container div